# jquery replace part of a class name with pattern

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, replace

I select all classes by class that begins with `photo-`. Replace part of class name by pattern. I need to replace `photo-gallery-RID459852` with `photo-gallery`. Note: the part `-RID[0-9]` is replaced by `""`

```js
$("#Master [class*='photo-']").replace(function(index, css) {
  return (css.match(/(^|\s)-RID\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
}, "");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="Master">
  <div class="photo-gallery-RID459852 other any some">
    Algo
  </div>
  <div class="photo-gallery-RID987410 other any some2 other2"></div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="photo-gallery-369841 other any some"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>
    <div class="photo-gallery-RID36541 here now other any some"></div>
  </article>
</main>
```

My jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ngqku78p/

Comment: Please see the console error. You cannot code by wishful thinking. Look in the jQuery documentation how such things work. You need a .each()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work as jQuery objects do not have a `replace()` method.

To achieve the output you require you could loop over *every* class on the element and remove the `RIDXXX` from it's name. To do that you can use the `classList` collection along with the `replace()` method, like this:

```js
$("#Master [class*='photo-']").each(function(i, el) {
  el.classList.forEach(function(className) {
    el.classList.replace(className, className.replace(/\-RID\d+/g, ''));
  });
});
```

```css
.photo-gallery {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="Master">
  <div class="photo-gallery-RID459852 other any some">Algo</div>
  <div class="photo-gallery-RID987410 other any some2 other2">Lorem</div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="photo-gallery-369841 other any some">ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>
    <div class="photo-gallery-RID36541 here now other any some">dolor</div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Genius, perfect solution.

I did not know that this function did not exist in jQuery, well when you write code between javascript and jQuery you confuse everything, when you are in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant this?

You could loop over the classList but this works for your examples too

```js
$("#Master [class*='photo-']").each(function() {
  console.log("Before", this.className)
  this.className = this.className.replace(/photo-gallery-RID.*? /g, "photo-gallery ");
  console.log("After ", this.className)
});
```

```css
.photo-gallery {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.other {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="Master">
  <div class="photo-gallery-RID459852 other any some">
    Algo
  </div>
  <div class="photo-gallery-RID987410 other any some2 other2">RID987410</div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="photo-gallery-369841 other any some">369841</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article>
    <div class="photo-gallery-RID36541 here now other any some">RID36541</div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Much better than mine. Not even sure why I put the loop in there.

Comment: Hmm, I liked yours since it does not add a spurious space if there are no other classes

Comment: True. I guess both have their benefits depending on the exact use case.

Comment: Thank you both for your solution.